# Not able to access inner class converter in xaml Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a abstract visiblitycoverter class which is derived by another inner class in same namespace.

```
namespace Converters
{
public abstract class OrientationToValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{

    //my code
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class OrientationToVisibilityConverter : OrientationToValueConverter<Visibility>
{
}
}
```

whenever I am defining it under resource property of xaml i am getting error
my xaml:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <converters:OrientationToVisibilityConverter x:Key="PortraitVisible" LandscapeValue="Collapsed" PortraitValue="Visible" />
    <converters:OrientationToVisibilityConverter x:Key="LandscapeVisible" LandscapeValue="Visible" PortraitValue="Collapsed" />

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I am getting error on both the definition.I have also defined its namespace in xaml but still not accessible and giving error as "OrientationToVisibilityConverter does not exist in the namespace Converters"

Comment: have you defined the namespace xmlns:converters="...." at the top of your xaml page?

Comment: yes as xmlns:onverters="clr-namespace:Converters"

Comment: did you typo your comment or did u define it as xmlns:onverters?

Comment: @wankr yes i have defined it in namespace as xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Converters" in my xaml